# Possible to .slideToggle() a specific <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have an `<ul>` of nav links.  One particular `<li>` is actually turned into 3 links.  Would like that particular `<li>` to slide open and closed to reveal the other three links.

Hosted [here.](http://students.thenet.ca/dcameron/)

```
<ul id="courseLinks">
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 1</strong> introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="./homework/week2/week2homework.htm"><strong>Week 2</strong> dev tools + standards</a></li>
    <li><a href="./homework/week3/week3homework.htm"><strong>Week 3</strong> HTML 5 &amp; SEO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="homeworkSlide"><strong>Week 4</strong> css concepts</a></li>
    <li id="slider"><a href="homework/week4/exercise1.htm">Exercise 1</a>
            <a href="homework/week4/exercise2.htm">Exercise 2</a>
            <a href="homework/week4/week4homework.htm">Homework</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 5</strong> advanced css</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 6</strong> server side includes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 7</strong> site construction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 8</strong> development methodology 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 9</strong> user experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 10</strong> social software</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 11</strong> project work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Week 12</strong> final examination</a></li>
</ul><!--nav-->
```

Jquery:

```
$('#homeworkSlide').click(function() {
  $('#slider').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Refuses to work.  Self teaching javascript at this point, is it not possible to modify `<ul>` in this fashion?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Works for me! http://jsfiddle.net/ZAHZ2/

Comment: Ummmm...for clarity.
Trying to press 'Week 4 CSS Concepts' on the page and have it drop down to display the three other links.  I've tried this on three different browsers with all degrees of refresh, with no success.  It's working for you?

Comment: we get what you mean. It's just, the code you've provided works. See my example above.

Comment: Sorry, missed that link.  Strange that it's not working where I'm hosting it, code is copy & paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read the source code on your [host](http://students.thenet.ca/dcameron/javascript/slide.js), and found that the binding operation is not bound in a `$(document).ready(...)`, and that may be the reason.

So, modify the code.

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#homeworkSlide').click(function() {
      $('#slider').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

That code works fine for me on that page when pasted into the console. Make sure you are running it on DOM ready

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: My answer was the suggestion to make sure the code was run when the DOM is ready. I didn't see the code on the demo page, but I may have missed it.